Is it possible to somehow create a short alias to variable in Inno Setup Pascal Script
In my function I want to create a shorthand for variable to shorten the code but if I understand it correctly, Pascal Script used in Inno Setup doesn't support neither pointers nor references, am I right? Are there any other ways to do that? This is the example of what I want to achieve (using Pascal pointers):
[Code]
var
  // Long names example
  MagicElementsOfStrangeButter: Array of Integer;
  IndexOfSelectedLongCurve: Integer;

// Example
procedure MyProcedure();
begin
  MagicElementsOfStrangeButter[IndexOfSelectedLongCurve] := 7;
  // More code that uses MagicElementsOfStrangeButter[IndexOfSelectedLongCurve]
  // Note: I don't want to create a local copy of target variable, use it, and then assign it to original variable.
end;

// Desired look
procedure MyProcedure();
  Temp: ^Integer;
begin
  Temp := @MagicElementsOfStrangeButter[IndexOfSelectedLongCurve];
  Temp^ := 7;
  // More code that uses Temp
end;


You're absolutely correct - PascalScript does not support pointers or passing by reference, so you're out of luck.

@KenWhite "Passing by reference" is supported. You probably mean "assigning local reference".

@qloq You might use preprocessor define/macro, but I do not think the resulting syntax would be nice.

"I don't want to create a local copy of target variable, use it, and then assign it to original variable." That sounds like a viable option if you want less typing.

@Bill_Stewart, it seems I'm a little bit spoiled with "big" languages and I don't like copying) I have some large records and dispite even they possibly can be copied without lags, I don't like it

Well, since PascalScript doesn't support pointers, you'll have to adjust to that reality.

Yes, I had already gotten it.
